# Call Trait method inside model event closure

Tags: laravel

This throws an error:

```php
use App\Traits\Test;

class Post extends Model {
    
    use Test;

    static::updated(function ($product) {
        $this->foo();
    });
}
```

In `App\Traits\Test`

```php
trait Test {
  private function foo() {
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I use `foo()` from the trait `Test` in the `Post` model event closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use instance methods inside static class methods is not permissible. It will throw an error "Using $this in static context"

So there are two options

```php
use App\Traits\Test;

class Post extends Model 
{
    
    use Test;

    static::updated(function ($product) {
        $instance = new static;
        $instance->foo();
    });

    //...
}


namespace App\Traits;

trait Test 
{
    private function foo() 
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

OR declare the method as static method in the trait

```php
use App\Traits\Test;

class Post extends Model 
{
    
    use Test;

    static::updated(function ($product) {
        static::foo();
    });

    //...
}



namespace App\Traits;

trait Test 
{
    private static function foo() 
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

There's also an option to boot the trait and hook into the boot method of trait to define model events in a trait - for that a static method with public visibility must be defined in the trait following the convention of `bootNameOfTrait`

```
namespace App\Traits;


trait Test 
{

    public static function bootTest()
    {
        static::updated(function($product){
            static::foo();
            //other processing as if defined on model class
        });
    }

    private static function foo() 
    {
      ...
    }
}


use App\Traits\Test;

class Post extends Model 
{
    
    use Test;

}
```